# Commutative integral domain with d.c.c. is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a commutative integral domain and it also satisfies descending chain condition on its ideals then how will we show that such ring $R$ will be a field?

Comment: I know little bit about them. Like every right artinian ring is right noetherian.

Comment: As one can see from the answer below it's enough to assume D.C.C. on principal ideals.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If we assume that $R$ has a unit $1_R$ which acts as a multiplicative identity element, i.e. 
$1_Rs = s1_R = s$ for all $s \in R$, which seems to be the typical assumption according to 
[this widipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain), then we can argue as follows:

For any $0 \ne a \in R$, consider the principal ideals $a^iR = \langle a^i \rangle$.  Since $a^{n + 1}r = a^n(ar)$ for any $r \in R$, we have $a^{n + 1}R \subseteq a^nR$; thus we have a descending chain of ideals

$aR \supseteq a^2r \supseteq . . . \supseteq a^nR \supseteq a^{n + 1}R \supseteq . . . , \tag{1}$

which must stabilize since $R$ is Artinian.  Thus we can assume

$a^{m + 1}R = a^mR \tag{2}$

for some positive integer $m$.  Then since $a^m = a^m1_R \in a^mR$, there must exist $s \in R$ with

$a^{m + 1}s = a^m, \tag{3}$

or

$a^m(1_R - as) = 0. \tag{4}$

Using the ID properties of $R$, this yields

$as = 1_R, \tag{5}$

since $a \ne 0 \Rightarrow a^m \ne 0$, again since $R$ is an integral domain.  We have shown that every $0 \ne a \in R$ has a multiplicative inverse; hence, $R$ is a field. ***QED***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you :) you are amazing Robert. Let me grasp it.

Comment: @Mat He Mat Cian:  Aw, shucks!  But glad to be of service, and a sincere thanks for the kind words!

Comment: Alternatively, we could also start by observing $R$ has a minimal right ideal $xR\neq\{0\}$ (necessarily cyclic by minimality.) Since $(xR)^2=xR$, there exists $r$ such that $x=x^2r$, and then the idea about $x(1-xr)$ applies again.

Comment: @RobertLewis:What is the example of such Integral domain??

Comment: @PKStyles:  well, the question is sort of ironic in that if you had such an integral domain then it would be a field $\Bbb F$, so the only ideals would be $\{0\}$ and $\Bbb F$ itself, and the whole proof sort of collapses.  So I guess I would say an example of such a domain would be any field $\Bbb F$.  Clearly $\Bbb F$ is trivially Artinian.

Comment: @RobertLewis:I saw this post last night,from that moment i'm thinking of an example... every time i end up with a field.Don't you think that such problems are total wastage of time,as the only ideals of Fields are trivial ones??

Comment: @PKStyles:  no, not a waste of time.  The point is that, *a priori*, we don't *know* if such integral domains are fields.  So with this proof we deduce the structure of such domains, and then if we encounter such conditions as in the hypothesis of the problem, we know we are dealing with a field.  It is sort of a standard classification, I think.

Comment: @RobertLewis:you're a good teacher!!!Fiat Lux!!!

Comment: @PKStyles.  Thank you, sir.  ***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @RobertLewis Why doesn't this same proof work to show that an integral domain that is Noetherian is a field?

Comment: @Junglemath:  The first thing which comes to mind is that the ideals $a^nR$ form a descending chain but not an ascending one.  Right?  From there I can't see how to force $a^{n + 1}R = a^nR$, which is what makes this proof fly. OK?  I mean, the $a^nR$ can be viewed as an ascending chain, but the finiteness condition doesn't show it stabilizes before we hit $aR$, so the argument breaks down.  Seen?