# R ring is noetherian, commutative, unitary and integral domain, is R a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

This is the question: "let R be a commutative unitary ring that is also integral domain and noetherian, prove that R is a field"

I'm having some trouble proving this. For R to be noehterian means that every ideal is finitely generated. Equivalently, for every non-empty ascending chain of ideals there is a maximal element. How do I prove that R is a field, that is, all of its elements have a muliplicative inverse?

Thanks in advance, please notify me if this question has already been answered before and point me to it, thank you.

Comment: It doesn't seem true to me. What about $k[x]$. That is a integral domain, and a PID so noetherian but it isn't a field. Or how about $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Hint: It need not be a field. Have you tried the simplest example of an integral domain which is not field?

Comment: Yes, i see. I must have confused the condition of Noetherian ring for the artinian ones. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it's pretty clear from TheNumber23's example $k[x]$ for fields $k$ that $R$ doesn't have to be a field; but if "Noetherian is replaced by "Artinian", the assertion becomes true.  See this:  [Commutative integral domain with d.c.c. is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574179/commutative-integral-domain-with-d-c-c-is-a-field).

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will look at this other article and see if i can solve the problem.

Comment: @Kirtash Riku:  no prolem!  Glad to be of assistance.  And thanks for the "acceptance".

Comment: Read your solution for the other post and got it perfectly, thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure, sir!