# Every prime ideal is max. if anysequence $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 \supseteq \cdots $ stabilises?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a comutative ring with $1 \neq 0 $. Assume that for every sequence of ideals $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq I_3 \supseteq \cdots $ there is a $N$ such that 
$$
n,m \geq N \quad \Longrightarrow \quad I_n=I_m
$$
Show that every prime ideal in this ring is maximal.

---

I don't know what I can do to prove it. A small hint please?

Comment: It's a more exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/574179/29335 but that question is a duplicate of the suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Your ring is called Artinian.

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $R$, then $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is an Artinian integral domain. For any $x$, consider the sequence of principal ideals of $R/\mathfrak{p}$
$$(x)\supseteq (x^2)\supseteq\cdots\supseteq (x^n)\supseteq\cdots$$
The fact that sequence stops implies ...