# Proving the ring $\mathbb{Q}$[$\mathbb{Z}$] is not artinian

Tags: ring-theory

My proposed solution:

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Q}$[$2^{n}\mathbb{Z}$] is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$[$\mathbb{Z}$] (I think) and so we have the following infinite descending chain of ideals:

$\mathbb{Q}$[$2\mathbb{Z}$] $\supsetneq$ $\mathbb{Q}$[$4\mathbb{Z}$] ... $\supsetneq$ $\mathbb{Q}$[$2^{n}\mathbb{Z}$] $\supsetneq$ ...

So the result follows.

Is this ok? Thanks.

Comment: When you are not sure, why not checking the steps in the argument for yourself? There is no obstacle.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[n \mathbb{Z}]$ is not an ideal, since it is a proper subset containing $1$, so your argument does not work.

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you. Any hint on how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Show $\Bbb Q[\Bbb Z]$ is isomorphic to the [Laurent polynomials](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) $\Bbb Q[x,x^{-1}]$ via an obvious map.

That ring is a domain. But an Artinian domain [is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/574179/29335). Is our ring a field?