# Condition on a prime ideal that implies it is maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

If $P$ is a prime ideal in a ring $R$, and if $P$ is contained in only finitely many right ideals of $R$, show that $P$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

I'm honestly not sure where to start with this. Are there any hints?

Comment: If a prime ideal is in the intersection of finitely many ideals, this implies another condition about containment between these ideals and the prime ideal. Think about the definition of prime ideals.

Answer (score 2):

After factoring by $P$ the question reduces to the
same question with $P=0$, which can be stated as:
Show that if $R$ is a prime ring with finitely many right ideals,
then $R$ is simple. [$R$ is prime means its zero ideal is a prime
ideal, and $R$ is simple means its zero ideal is maximal.]

Reason the statement is true:

As Curious noted, having finitely many right ideals
implies that $R$ is right Artinian. This forces the Jacobson radical
$J=J(R)$ to be nilpotent.
But $R$ is prime, so any nilpotent ideal of $R$ is zero.
This implies that $R$ is Artinian and Jacobson semisimple, which
implies that $R$ is semisimple. But a prime semisimple
ring is simple by the Wedderburn-Artin Theorem.

We can go a little bit further than required.
The Wedderburn-Artin Theorem shows that $R\cong M_n(D)$
for some $n$ and some division ring $D$. But such
rings usually have infinitely many right ideals.
The exceptions are when $R$ itself is a division ring,
or $R$ is finite. So one can reword the original problem as:

Show that if $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ that is contained
in finitely many right ideals, then either
$P$ is maximal as a right ideal in $R$ or else $P$ is
maximal as a 2-sided ideal of $R$ and $P$ has finite index in $R$.

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then $R/P$ is an integral domain. Since ideals in $R/P$ correspond to ideals in $R$ containing $P$, we have that $R/P$ has only finitely many ideals. Such a ring is Artinian. One can use this fact to show any nonzero element has an inverse (for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574179/commutative-integral-domain-with-d-c-c-is-a-field)). Thus, $R/P$ is in fact a field, which happens if and only if $P$ is maximal, and we are done.

Comment: Wait, are your rings commutative or not? I can't tell because you refer to right ideals, and one does not usually bother saying that with commutative rings.

Comment: It matters because if you are using noncommutative rings your answer is wrong

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, good point, we don't know $R$ is commutative. I'll have to think a bit more about why that's true. Given the assumptions though, it seems like it does want you to show $R/P$ is a field.

Comment: The solution Keith spelled out is what I was steering you toward. The analogous thing is true for noncommutative rings, but it concerns prime and simple rings rather than domains and fields.